# ¿Qué opináis sobre el uso de una web como "Let me google that for you"?

Tags: discusión, comentarios, convenciones-sociales

Pues eso ¿Qué opina la comunidad de **Stack Overflow en español** sobre el uso de una web como [lmgtfy.com](http://lmgtfy.com/)?

En alguna ocasión, la he usado en los comentarios de preguntas que se hubieran solucionado con una simple búsqueda en google o similares. Siempre me ha parecido una forma graciosa de enseñar a la gente a ser un poco más proactivos y autosuficientes. En una conversación en el chat, sin embargo, me comentaron que no estaba bien visto su uso e incluso alguien (no recuerdo ahora mismo quién) usó ([mal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ABa92po)) el termino *condescendiente*. Desde entonces he buscado en esta comunidad alguna referencia a la buena o mala opinión sobre su uso, pero no he logrado encontrar nada que se decante por una u otra. Entonces ¿Qué opináis?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=why+is+lmgtfy+considered+rude

Comment: En [so] de hecho no es posible añadir un comentario con un enlace a lmgtfy. Aqui tienes una pregunta en meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255397/579895 .

Comment: @Pikoh desde 2009 está prohibido usarlo en SO ([Ban LMGTFY (let me google that for you) links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650/209901))

Comment: @fedorqui curiosamente la respuesta mas votada en ese post aboga por no banear los enlaces a LMGTFY :)

Comment: Entiendo que eso son decisiones tomadas en SO, pero qué ocurren en SOes ?

Comment: Muriano: ¿podrías poner algún ejemplo de comentario en el que hayas utilizado esta herramienta? Por otra parte, lo del mal uso de _condescendiente_ queda cojo si no mencionas cómo lo usó quien lo usó mal.

Comment: @fedorqui, lo siento, creo que borré todos mis comentarios de este tipo, ahora mismo no tengo ninguno a mano. Sobre el mal uso de *condescendiente*, me refiero a su uso como traducción del inglés *condescendence*, cuyo significado en ese idioma no está recogido por la rae en español (donde solo tiene un valor "positivo")

Comment: Pues ya que estamos pregunté en [spanish.se] →[¿Es correcto usar “condescender” para hablar de tratar a alguien con superioridad?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22290/1674)

Comment: Opino que la pagina es graciosa pero es más constructivo para el usuario hacerle saber la importancia de investigar por su cuenta antes de formular una pregunta, que el pegarle ese enlace

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aunque se puede mostrar un enlace de LMGTFY, la idea no es de responder con comentarios sarcásticos sino de educar a la gente a hacer sus propias búsquedas.

Lo que recomendaría sería lo siguiente:

- ignorar la pregunta por completo
- dejar un comentario pidiéndole al usuario que investigue por su cuenta y proporcione un mejor pregunta ya bien investigada
- votar negativamente después de dejar el comentario haciéndole saber al usuario que se votó de esa manera porque no estaba la pregunta bien formulada

Lo que queremos evitar es un ambiente descortés y frío. Queremos que la gente sepa la razón por la que una pregunta así no va a ser recibida con mucho entusiasmo sin hacerlos sentirse como imbéciles. Uno nunca sabe las razones por las que alguien pregunta así.

¡Formemos una comunidad cálida y de calidad!

Comment: Juan, si mal no recuerdo, en el sitio en inglés no se pueden poner comentarios con ese sitio. Se implementó dicha funcionalidad justo por el problema que menciona Muriano. Aquí una pregunta en Meta SOes al respecto: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255397/1065197